# Getting Kivy Attribute Error 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, label, kivy-language

```
TraceBack error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
KeyError: 'text_label'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/App/main_app.py", line 29, in correct
    self.ids.text_label.text = "Correct"
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/App/main_app.py", line 383, in button_press
    MyLayout().correct()
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/App/color.kv", line 26, in <module>
    on_press: app.button_press()
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/App/main_app.py", line 410, in <module>
    colorApp().run()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Getting the Error: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'
Not sure why this is occuring I call for a function at the end of my button_press function and this error comes up when the file tries to run the function (both functions are in a different class). I am trying to dynamically update the text of a label. I've tried other solutions from people on StackOverflow but they don't work for me (or maybe I'm doing them wrong).

Code(Some useless parts removed):

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import random
import os
from kivy.core.window import Window
import numpy as np
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
imp = "x"
user_inp = "x"


class MyLayout(Widget):
    #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SEEMS TO OCCUR
    def correct(self):

        self.ids.text_label.text = "Correct"
        return RootLayout()
    def incorrect(self):
        self.ids.text_label.text = "Incorrect"
        return RootLayout()
        

class RootLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

prior = StringProperty()

class colorApp(App, FloatLayout):

    flagfile = StringProperty("0")
    
    path = "/Users/sam/Downloads/App/w320"
    files = os.listdir(path)
    #self.important = random.choice(files)
    important = "bt.png"
    flagfile= path + "/" + important
    
    other_answer = StringProperty()
  
    prior = StringProperty()
    def button_press(self):
        #[Removed Code]
 
        print(self.correct_answer)
        self.imp = self.correct_answer
        
        self.prior = self.root.ids.user_input.text.lower()

        user_inp = self.prior

        #THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE FUNCTION <------
        if user_inp == self.imp:   
            MyLayout().correct()
        else:
            MyLayout().incorrect()
        
        print(self.prior)
        print(self.imp)
        print(self.important)
        print(user_inp)

        return RootLayout()

    def build(self):
        return RootLayout()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    colorApp().run()
```

Kivy

```
<RootLayout>
    MyLayout:  
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size: root.width, root.height

            padding: 50
            spacing: 20
            Image:
                id: cardimage
                #source: app.flagfile
                source: "w320/bt.png"
            
            TextInput:
                multiline: False
                text: "Enter Guess Here"
                on_focus: self.text = "" if args[1] else self.text
                id: user_input
                
            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                font_size: 32
                on_press: app.button_press()
            
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                text:'32'
                pos: 1200, 910
                id: text_label
                font_size: 75
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I included it in my post.

Comment: this example doesn't produce an error message, because the code isn't functional.  Why are you calling MyLayout().correct()  instead of directly updating text_label?  Also, why are you trying to create new instances of widgets that aren't registered to the layout via add_widget call, just to try to update some other widgets text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if user_inp == self.imp:   
        self.correct()
    else:
        self.incorrect()
```

If that doesn't work try not to create new instance of MyLayout, but just refer to one:

```
if user_inp == self.imp:   
    MyLayout.correct()
else:
    MyLayout.incorrect()
```

In all cases Traceback would be helpful.

Comment: Still getting the error not sure why? I added the traceback error if that helps. Thanks for the help.